# mysql user creation with % to host , can only log on from remote host

Tags: mysql

Using MySQL v5.1.52

After creating a mysql user with the following commands:

```
create user 'user1'@'%' identified by 'pass1';
grant select on db1.* to 'user1';
flush privileges;
```

Then doing a 'mysql -uuser1 -p' in the command line then entering the password I still get this error:

```
Enter password:
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'user1'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
```

However when connecting from a remote system (with the -h) to the above server using the above credentials it works.

Why can I not log on locally with this user?

Here is the user/host outpout:

```
mysql> select User,Host from mysql.user;
+----------------+-----------------+
| User           | Host            |
+----------------+-----------------+
| user1          | %               |
```

Answer (score 3):

When connecting to your localhost it's going you use sockets instead of ports to connect.  Those grants need a specific 'localhost' grant.  To use your % grant locally connect specifying you want to connect via TCP

```
mysql -u user -p --proto=TCP
```

[Further reading](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/can-not-connect-to-server.html)

Comment: Thanks that did it.
Strange on Ubuntu it seems to work without the --proto=TCP but on RHEL I guess you need it.

Comment: It's worth pointing out this is probably bad practice for production configurations.

Comment: how so? what would be the correct syntax to add users in that case?

Comment: Security.  If you only want a user to connect via localhost then specify @'localhost' in the grant.  Using '%' potentially allows connections from any internet address (assuming your port is open to that).  It's more prudent to restrict the credentials to your network.  e.g. 'user'@'10.1.%'

Answer (score 1):

In MySQL 'localhost' and '127.0.0.1' have different meanings. The former will attempt to connect via the socket file, the latter will go via TCP.

To connect to a user defined with `@%` (any host), you'll want to connect using TCP, as suggested in [@atxdba's](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/10741/180) answer.

An alternative way would be to provide the host '127.0.0.1':

```
mysql -h127.0.0.1 -uuser -p
```

The `mysql` command line will also try to read from user configs in the [client] section of an option file (which is located in /etc/my.cnf usually, as well as any overrides like ~/.my.cnf).

So if one of those files has a section like this:

```
[client]
host=127.0.0.1
```

Then mysql will automatically try to connect via TCP.